# Grunt 'No Express Targets Found' With load-grunt-config

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

When the grunt module `load-grunt-config` for my express configuration, I get `No "express" targets found.`. I clarified with `grunt  load-grunt-config --config-debug` it is finding it correctly. What exactly am I doing wrong?

DEBUG:

```
one@node ~/github/simple-load-balancer-service/lbs $ grunt  load-grunt-config --config-debug
{
  "express": {
    "prod": {
      "options": {
        "port": 9000,
        "script": "app.js"
      }
    }
  },
  "package": {
    "name": "app",
    "description": "simple-angular",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "4.x",
      "express-multi-proxy-router": "*",
      "body-parser": "*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "latest",
      "testem": "latest",
      "jasmine": "latest",
      "phantomjs": "latest",
      "load-grunt-tasks": "latest",
      "load-grunt-config": "latest",
      "grunt-bower-install": "latest",
      "grunt-contrib-watch": "latest",
      "grunt-contrib-connect": "latest",
      "grunt-express-server": "latest",
      "grunt-open": "latest",
      "grunt-contrib-coffee": "latest",
      "grunt-contrib-less": "latest",
      "grunt-injector": "latest",
      "grunt-testem": "latest",
      "grunt-bowercopy": "latest",
      "grunt-reload": "latest"
    }
  }
}
```

---

grunt/express.js"

```
one@node ~/github/simple-load-balancer-service/lbs $ cat grunt/express.js 
module.exports = {
  prod: {
    options: {
      port: 9000,
      script: 'app.js',
    }
  }
};
```

---

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig({
    //Todo: clean up file path directives
        watch: {
        express: {
        files: ['app/static/**',
             'app/scripts/**',
            'app.js'],
        tasks: ['express:prod'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
            livereload: true
        }
        },
        files: ['app/static/**',
                'app/scripts/**',
            'app.js'],
        tasks: ['reload'],
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'start server', function() {
        grunt.task.run('express');
        //  Uncomment grunt.task.run('open') if you plan on running on running on 
        //  just 127.0.0.1 rather than all interfaces 0.0.0.0
        //grunt.task.run('open');
        //grunt.task.run('bowerInstall');
        //grunt.task.run('coffee');
        //grunt.task.run('less');
        //grunt.task.run('injector');
        grunt.task.run('watch');
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have a task called "express"?

Comment: Your task appears to be named "watch" and not "express" ("express" is inside the *watch* object).

Comment: With `load-grunt-config` it looks in `grunt/express.js` and loads the express task. This is why you do not see it in Gruntfile.js. Please ignore the watch task.